# How to post & get data into web page in android

Tags: android

Im doing T-shirt online purchasing app.When user select one product & do payment using paypal.so i need to send data(such as product & user details) to paypal & have to retrieve data from paypal.How can i post & get data into paypal.?I've no idea on that..

Answer (score 0):

paypal provides an API for the android platform, have a look at  the
[PayPal API](https://www.x.com/index.jspa)

Comment: Thank you for ur reply..But i dont have any idea on that.Do u have any sample codes to do that?

Comment: no, but paypal might have, you can find anything you need there